# Mongodb C# and SELECT nested value

Tags: c#, mongodb, select, nested

I'm trying to do a simple select in mongodb with some C# code :

```
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa04a34294f9c8f6c0ead85"), 
"Categorie" : "smartphone", 
"Plafond" : 1000.0, 
"SousCategorie" : [
    {
        "SousCategorieLibelle" : " 100-300 ", 
        "ValeurMin" : 100.0, 
        "ValeurMax" : 300.0, 
        "GarantieTarif" : [
            {
                "GarantieCode" : "VOL", 
                "GarantieLibelle" : "Vol", 
                "HT" : 0.09, 
                "Taxe" : 0.01, 
                "TTC" : 0.1, 
                "Franchise" : 50.0
            }, 
            {
                "GarantieCode" : "BOD", 
                "GarantieLibelle" : "Casse et Oxydation", 
                "HT" : 0.06, 
                "Taxe" : 0.01, 
                "TTC" : 0.07, 
                "Franchise" : 50.0
            }, 
            {
                "GarantieCode" : "CAT", 
                "GarantieLibelle" : "Catastrophes naturelles", 
                "HT" : 0.01, 
                "Taxe" : 0.01, 
                "TTC" : 0.02, 
                "Franchise" : 190.0
            }, 
            {
                "GarantieCode" : "CTEC", 
                "GarantieLibelle" : "Catastrophes technologiques", 
                "HT" : 0.0, 
                "Taxe" : 0.0, 
                "TTC" : 0.0, 
                "Franchise" : 50.0
            }
        ]
    }
], 
"Frais" : 0.02, 
"Commission" : 0.02
```

In C# i m using this code :

```
 protected async void ddlcategorie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tarifs");

        BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument();
        filter.Add("Categorie", "smartphone");

        using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                var batch = cursor.Current;
                foreach (BsonDocument document in batch)
                {                       
                    txtValeur.Text += document["SousCategorie"]["SousCategorieLibelle"];
                 //   txtValeur.Text += document[1][2];
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And i m always get a error :

> System.NotSupportedException : 'BsonArray does not support indexing by
>   name (only BsonDocument does).'

but if I ask `document.GetType().ToString();` I get MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.

What I am supposed to do?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that property `"SousCategorie"` is an array (the first char after `:` is `[`), so when indexing `document["SousCategorie"]` is correct but returns BsonArray. As I understand it is one element array so you can take the first element (using index 0 or `First()`) and then access needed property

Probably the following code will work but I didn't test it:

```
foreach(var category in document["SousCategorie"])
{
   Console.WriteLine(category["SousCategorieLibelle"));
}
```

Comment: My query returns more than 1 result (3 exactly)
For 1 catégorie ("smartphone") I want to get these 3 SousCategorie.SousCategorieLibelle (100-300, 300-500, 500-1000)

Comment: So iterate through them and get all of them. You can use foreach or Select

Comment: i m trying but i dont know how to reatch nested item

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected async void ddlcategorie_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tarifs");

    BsonDocument filter = new BsonDocument();
    BsonDocument projection = new BsonDocument();
    projection.Add("Categorie", 1);
    projection.Add("SousCategorie.ValeurMin", 1);
    projection.Add("SousCategorie.SousCategorieLibelle", 1);

    var options = new FindOptions<BsonDocument>()
    {
        Projection = projection
    };

    using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter, options))
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            var batch = cursor.Current;
            foreach (BsonDocument document in batch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(document.ToJson());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I m tring to get "SousCategorie.SousCategorieLibelle" Value

```
>? document["SousCategorie"][0].ToString()
"{ \"SousCategorieLibelle\" : \" 100-300 \", \"ValeurMin\" : 100.0 }"
>? document["SousCategorie"][0]
{{ "SousCategorieLibelle" : " 100-300 ", "ValeurMin" : 100.0 }}


>? document["SousCategorie.SousCategorieLibelle"].ToString()
'document["SousCategorie.SousCategorieLibelle"].ToString()' a levé une exception de type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
```

I dont understand how i can get deeper in my database